# Phalcon: get url params

Tags: php, phalcon, dispatcher

I am trying to handle GET params directly in controller with dispatcher, but result is `NULL`.

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller{

   public function showAction(){
       $year = $this->dispatcher->getParam("year");

       var_dump($year); //returns NULL;
   }
}
```

My url is like http://example.com/post/show/2015

I tried as well: 
                http://example.com/post/show?year=2015
                http://example.com/post/show/year/2015

How should i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatcher handles route parameters.

For this `$this->dispatcher->getParam("year");` to work you need to define "year" in your route:

```
$router->add('/post/show/{year}', 'Posts::show')->setName('postShow');
```

---

If your url looked like this: http://example.com/post/show?year=2015 to access the year you have to use the `Request` class.

```
$this->request()->getQuery('year', 'int', 2012);
```

'year' - name of the query parameter;

'int' - sanitization;

2012 - default value (if you need it).

Comment: I did a bit research and saw that solution before.  This code is snippet is from phalcon documentation:  https://docs.phalconphp.com/bg/3.2/controllers
You can get an arbitrary parameter from its name in the following way:

   use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
    class PostsController extends Controller{
      public function showAction(){
         $year      = $this->dispatcher->getParam('year');
         $postTitle = $this->dispatcher->getParam('postTitle');
      }
    }
That's the point I don't understand, they used it directly in contoller

Comment: They have named parameters in their routes. It is just not shown in this section of docs. Read section "Parameters with Names" here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/bg/3.2/routing and you will understand :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I will read doc link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is following the expected `/[controller]/[action]/[parameter]` format, so all you need to do is make `$year` a parameter passed to `showAction()`:

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller{

   public function showAction($year){

       var_dump($year); //returns NULL;
   }
}
```